# Remote Server behaving weirdly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to upload multiple images using paperclip gem. I have controller BatchImagesController, an associate batch images model and an attachment model image_assets. Now the issue is, my app is working fine on `localhost` in development and production environment. But on Remote server its not uploading images. The database shows `batch_images` entries but nothing uploads in `image_assets`. I am unable to debug here. Production log is also not showing anything. I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.13.

Any suggestion what I might be doing wrong?? Is this a mass assignment issue??I have made the

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

Comment: Could be a permission problem on the server so that he can't save the files.

Comment: I dont think permission as an issue. I have other attachments which is working fine. Problem is coming only in the cases where I have separate attachment model like in this case..image_assets for BatchImages.